# model validation summary errors alert box is disabled on .hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a postcode finder on my mvc web application form which is optional. If I dont get a post code match I appened the .validation-summary-errors with my own custom error message. Once the error has been corrected I remove all instances of class postcode in .validation-summary-errors and apply the hide method. The problem is when hiding the validation-summary-errors div disables the validation popup to show other form errors when submitting the form.

my javascript code

```
$("#AddressFinder").click(function () {

var postcode = $("#Address_Postcode").val();
$(".postcode-error").remove();
$(".validation-summary-errors").hide();

if (!postcode) {
    $(".validation-summary-errors ul").append("<li class='postcode-error'>Please include a postcode to search.</li>");
    $(".validation-summary-errors").show();
}
else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/Postcode/GetAddress",
        data: "{ 'postcode':'" + postcode + "' }",
        success: function (data) {
            if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                $(".validation-summary-errors").append("<li class='postcode-error'>There are no addresses matching your postcode</li>");
                $(".validation-summary-errors").show();
            }
            else {
                vm.addresses(data);
                addressList.show();

            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

how can i hide the valiidation-summary-errors div without it disabling when submitting the form to the controller?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix my issue. Your not suppose to use hide() or show(). Just add or remove the validation-summary-validation.

```
$("#AddressFinder").click(function () {

var postcode = $("#Address_Postcode").val();

if (!postcode) {
    $(".validation-summary-errors ul").append("<li class='postcode-error'>Please include a postcode to search.</li>");
    $(".validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-valid");
}
else {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "/Postcode/GetAddress",
        data: "{ 'postcode':'" + postcode + "' }",
        success: function (data) {
            if ($.isEmptyObject(data)) {
                $(".validation-summary-errors").append("<li class='postcode-error'>There are no addresses matching your postcode</li>");
                $(".validation-summary-errors").removeClass("validation-summary-valid");

            }
            else {
                vm.addresses(data);
                addressList.show();
                $(".postcode-error").remove();
                $(".validation-summary-errors").addClass("validation-summary-valid");
            }
        }
    });
}
});
```

This way you still get the model validation messeges working when the form is submitted.